# convert TEXT value od date to UK DATE format in SQL

Tags: sql, date

I have a Database column with the DATE as text value for example 
10215 which is (01/02/2015) 100215 which is 10/02/2015 (DDMMYYYY) UK format

How do I convert this into SQL Date format with within SQLview statement

Thanks you

Comment: Use proper data types... And tag the dbms you're using. (When it comes to date/time many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Microsoft SQL Server, we manipulate the string as following:

- pad the string with a leading `0` (in case it was lost)
- take right-most 6 characters
- insert `/`'s between day and month, and between month and year
- use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx) function with British/French format (#3) to convert value to a date

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0'+[Date_Column],6),3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'), 3)
```

Comment: This is worked, but for some reason its YYYY-MM-DD what do I change in above script to display as DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: What you see in SSMS is just a representation of the date value. If you need to export the data in a particular format, use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx) with a required _style_.